# Are transistors on MMICs considered lumped elements?

Tags: amplifier, rf, electromagnetism, transmission-line, microwave

Are transistors, in practice, always small enough to be considered lumped elements in Monolithic Microwave Integrated Circuits (MMICs)? Similarly for discrete transistors used in hybrid microwave circuits.

Material I have found on small-signal microwave amplifier design typically starts from the network parameters of some transistor, measured at a particular DC bias point. The S-parameters of such a biased device can be measured but I don't have any intuitive idea of how the device physics, which I generally see presented in terms of voltages and currents, not taking into account more general field analysis, relates to this

If I was analysing, say, a small-signal Common-Source FET amplifier for audio purposes, I would be thinking about it in terms of the Gate-to-Source voltage modulating the drain current which would be turned into a potentially larger voltage signal by a load impedance. This doesn't take into account anything about transmission line theory and travelling waves.

I am generally familiar with the principles of devices like Travelling Wave Tube Amplifiers but have never been involved in the design of one. I am also aware of solid-state distributed amplifiers, which to my knowledge have multiple transistors connected along transmission lines, but the individual transistors seem to be considered as lumped elements in the theory.

**NOTE:** I admit that this is not a terribly clearly phrased question, but I have struggled for years to understand how a transistor amplifies a travelling electromagnetic wave.

Comment: A transistor does not amplify a traveling EM wave.  An EM wave is a free space phenomena, that propagates (radiates) on its own.  A transistor amplifies, and interacts with a signal carried on a trace, or interconnect of some sort.

Comment: Think about what an S-parameter is.  It's simply the amplitude and phase relationship between two (or more) ports of a black box.  Those ports can be different (S21) or the same (S11 or S22). That black can be as simple as a wire (a transmission line), or as complicated as an entire receiver.

Comment: @SteveSh Hmm okay, if you have say a pulse travelling down a microstrip line though, isn't the energy really in the electric and magnetic fields which are guided by the trace and the ground plane?